# Cannot see the last row in my UiTableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView added in InterfaceBuilder. My app runs in LandScape. Because I was unable to use autorotation (still can't figure that out). I am using Transforming it for now. Having said that, I now have to place the UITableView in some weird position for it to look correct after transformation

My table is fine but I cannot reach to the last couple of rows in the table. It almost seems like its Cut Off.

What settings would be causing this?

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried logging your view's width and height? Maybe the view is just too big and scaling the UITableView to large?

I have had no problems with UITableViews and rotation so far.